# Using Autodesk's Forge OSS, I can upload to a bucket, but the body of the download is empty

Tags: javascript, node.js, object-storage, autodesk-forge

I'm using Autodesk's Forge Object Storage Service and while I can upload my file to my bucket, when I try to download it, the body comes out empty. However, when using `Head`, the Data-Size is correct.

Here is my upload (note that I'm using the signed url upload API):

```
            var url = uploadOptions.url;

            var fileReader = new FileReader();
            // UploadOptions.Body contains a Blob
            fileReader.readAsBinaryString(uploadOptions.Body);
            fileReader.onloadend = function (e) {
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                var lastLoadedValue = 0;
                xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                    if (xhr.readyState === 4 && (xhr.status === 200 || xhr.status === 201)) {
                        console.log('UPLOAD FINISHED:', xhr.responseText);
                        callback();
                    }
                };
                xhr.open("PUT", url, true);
                xhr.withCredentials = true;
                // uploadOptions.ContentType = 'application/octet-stream'
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', uploadOptions.ContentType);
                xhr.send(e.target.result);
```

Here is my download:

```
         superagent
            .get(_autodesk_api_baseurl
                + baseUrl
                + downloadOptions.bucket
                + '/objects/'
                + encodeURIComponent(downloadOptions.key))
            .set('Authorization', 'Bearer '
                + token.access_token)
            .query({'response-content-type': 'application/octet-stream'})
            .end(function (err, resp) {
                if (typeof callback === 'function') {
                    // All works fine
                    callback(undefined, resp);
                }
            });
```

And then, in the callback, I print my response and the body is empty.
I even wrote the JSON encoded response to a file to get this:

```
{
"req": {
    "method": "GET",
    "url": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/storage.vcs.prod.mevsg.autodesk.com/objects/assets%2FNT5NR9KJU2PH%2Fea02ec77505f2ea2defac93fe231764f2916e4d1aeaac7d92945a08a0086c60667369431361d5aa426d4cccca49b9e4c7cb70bc6ebf700258a3cb37617eacfa0"
},
"header": {
    "access-control-allow-credentials": "true",
    "access-control-allow-headers": "Authorization, Accept-Encoding, Range, Content-Type",
    "access-control-allow-methods": "GET",
    "access-control-allow-origin": "*",
    "content-disposition": "attachment; filename=\"ea02ec77505f2ea2defac93fe231764f2916e4d1aeaac7d92945a08a0086c60667369431361d5aa426d4cccca49b9e4c7cb70bc6ebf700258a3cb37617eacfa0\"",
    "content-encoding": "gzip",
    "content-type": "application/octet-stream",
    "date": "Thu, 30 Jun 2016 18:03:10 GMT",
    "etag": "\"8ad9c59b256cef48798a94c0295023088016d43a\"",
    "server": "Apigee Router",
    "vary": "Accept-Encoding",
    "transfer-encoding": "chunked",
    "connection": "Close"
},
"status": 200
```

}

As you can see, there is no body. But when I use `Head` on the object, I get the right number of bytes.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?
I tried hard-coding Content-Type to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and then I could download the file (there were bytes in the body), but the bytes were changed a little. For example, 208 (11010000) became 80 (1010000). As you can see, the first bit was reversed. With that content-type, I could not open the file. Which way should I use?

---

UPDATE:
With the help of Augusto, I found the problem.

1. Superagent doesn't seem to work, but Request does.
2. Not sure if it had an real impact, but I set the encoding for the downloaded buffer to base64
3. I needed to upload the Blob directly. I didn't have to use a FileReader to read the bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what solved the problem:

For the upload, I needed to only send the Blob. Here's the updated code:

```
    var url = uploadOptions.url;

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4 && (xhr.status === 200 || xhr.status === 201)) {
            console.log(xhr.status);
            console.log('UPLOAD FINISHED:', xhr.responseText);
            callback();
        }
    };

    xhr.open("PUT", url, true);
    xhr.withCredentials = true;
    // Send the Blob directly!!
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', uploadOptions.ContentType);
    xhr.send(uploadOptions.Body);
```

For the download, the library Superagent didn't work, but Request did. I also changed the encoding of the buffer to base64. Here's the code:

```
    request({
        url: _autodesk_api_baseurl
            + baseUrl
            + downloadOptions.bucket
            + '/objects/'
            + encodeURIComponent(downloadOptions.key),
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token.access_token
        },
        encoding: null
    }, function (error, response, body) {
        //Error handling goes here

        if (typeof callback === 'function') {
            callback(null, new Buffer(body, 'base64'));
        }
    });
```

After, that, I can just write the buffer to a file and open it. Thanks to those who helped answer.

Answer (score 0):

Don't believe you need content-type to download a file, [see more here](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-:bucketKey-objects-:objectName-GET/). Can you [request the details](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-:bucketKey-objects-:objectName-details-GET/) of the file?

This the curl to download it that should work:

```
curl -v "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/storage.vcs.prod.mevsg.autodesk.com/objects/assets%2FNT5NR9KJU2PH%2Fea02ec77505f2ea2defac93fe231764f2916e4d1aeaac7d92945a08a0086c60667369431361d5aa426d4cccca49b9e4c7cb70bc6ebf700258a3cb37617eacfa0"
  -X GET
  -H "Authorization: Bearer AbCdEfGhIjKlMnOpQrStUvXwYz"
```

And here is a code I used with NodeJS/Request module. It's in fact quite generic, but if I pass the /oss/ URL resource, it works fine. I'm not sure which library you're using, sorry.

```
function download(resource, token, onsuccess) {
    console.log('Downloading ' + config.baseURL + resource); // debug
    request({
        url: config.baseURL + resource,
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
        },
        encoding: null
    }, function (error, response, body) {
        onsuccess(new Buffer(body, 'base64'));
    });
}
```

Comment: Yes I can get the details of the file. I also tried to download with your cUrl (I had to generate a new token) and I could download the file correctly. So it confirms that the file is on the server. And the content-type was added later on when I tried anything to make it work, so that is not the answer. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I edited my answer with a code that I'm using (and works)

Comment: I tried your code. It worked, I get the body and I can write it to a file. So I guess it was just my library that had a problem or something that OSS doesn't like about it.
I can't open the file afterwards though. It is a 3ds Max file and when I open it, it says "File Open Failed". I guess it is a question of encoding. Anyway, unless you already know the problem from the code that's there, I'll try and if I can't figure it I'll ask another question.

Comment: it might be something on the encoding... I'm using: new Buffer(body,'base64')

Comment: Thanks again for your help, I managed to find the rest of the problem. It was my upload. I sent the bytes read, but I only had to send the Blob. Now everything works :)

Comment: nice! if you have time, please share the solution! love to vote it up! :-)

Answer (score 0):

This section doesn't seem right:

```
.query({'response-content-type': 'application/octet-stream'})
```

It should be

```
.set('response-content-type', 'application/octet-stream')
```

Anyway, Augusto is correct - you don't need to provide any additional header other than Authorization

Comment: The content-type was added later when I didn't know what else could fix it. So yeah, I'll remove it.